# Importing a tkinter program from another interface

Tags: python, string, tkinter, import

I have created a simple password generator using the secret module and created a Tkinter interface for it.
This is the program:

```
from tkinter import *
import secrets
import string

def pwd_generator(alphabet, pwd_length):
    pwd = ''

    for i in range(pwd_length):
        pwd += ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet))
    print(pwd)
    
    return pwd

def pwd_main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Password Generator")

    #Create labels and checkboxes:
    let_var = IntVar()
    Label(root, text="Letters").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    Checkbutton(root, variable=let_var).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, pady=5)

    dig_var = IntVar()
    Label(root, text="Digits").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    Checkbutton(root, variable=dig_var).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=5)

    spc_var = IntVar()
    Label(root, text="Special Characters").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    Checkbutton(root, variable=spc_var).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=5)

    #Create labels and text input:
    Label(root, text="Password Lenght").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    pwd_length = Entry(root, width=10, justify="right")
    pwd_length.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

    #Create button:
    Button(root, text="Generate", width=8, command=lambda: display_pwd()).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

    #Create result display:
    display = Entry(root, justify="right")
    display.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E, padx=5, pady=5)

    
    #Define variables:

    def get_instructions(let_var, dig_var, spc_var):
        letters = string.ascii_letters
        digits = string.digits
        special_chars = string.punctuation
        alphabet = ""

        if let_var == 1:
            alphabet += letters
        if dig_var == 1:
            alphabet += digits
        if spc_var == 1:
            alphabet += special_chars
        
        return alphabet

    def display_pwd():
        let_state = let_var.get()
        dig_state = dig_var.get()
        spc_state = spc_var.get()
        pwd_length_state = int(pwd_length.get())
        try:
            alphabet = get_instructions(let_state, dig_state, spc_state)
            pwd = pwd_generator(alphabet, pwd_length_state)
            clear_display()
            display.insert(0,pwd)
        except:
            clear_display()
            display.insert(0, 'Error')

    def clear_display():
        """It clears everything at the GUI display.
        Parameters: none
        Return: nothing
        """
        display.delete(0, END)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pwd_main()
```

It works just fine, but, I have another program called main.py that is just a button, when you click it, it opens the password generator, but when I do it that way, it no longer works.

The main.py is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from pass_gen import pwd_main

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Main Menu")

    #Create buttons:
    Button(root, text="Password\nGenerator", command=pwd_main).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    root.mainloop()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I was expecting for the imported program to work, just as it does when I run it from the pass_gen.py

I don't know what's wrong. The error message says:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jcamp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__        
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\jcamp\OneDrive\Documentos\byui\cse_111_final_project\pass_gen.py", line 37, in <lambda>
    Button(root, text="Generate", width=8, command=lambda: display_pwd()).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
  File "c:\Users\jcamp\OneDrive\Documentos\byui\cse_111_final_project\pass_gen.py", line 68, in display_pwd
    pwd = pwd_generator(alphabet, pwd_length_state)
  File "c:\Users\jcamp\OneDrive\Documentos\byui\cse_111_final_project\pass_gen.py", line 9, in pwd_generator
    pwd += ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet))
  File "C:\Users\jcamp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\random.py", line 378, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: It is because you have more than one instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: Yes, @acw1668 is right. pass_generator was supposed to be a Toplevel(). Now it works.